# What does this Python error mean?

Tags: python-3.x

This was my test code (Python 3.2)

```
import random

def singleMatch():
    a = random.randint(1, 5050)
    b = random.randint(1, 5050-a)
    c = 5050-a-b

    h = [a, b, c]
    print(h)
    computer = [841, 842, 3367]

    score = 0

    for i, j in zip(computer, h):
        if i > j:
            score = score + 1

    if score == 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0



def match(n):
    matchScore = 0
    for i in range(n):
        s = singleMatch()
        matchScore = matchScore + s
    return matchScore

x = match(10000)
print(x)
```

When I run the code, I sometimes get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Ercan\blotto.py", line 32, in <module>
    x = match(10000)
  File "D:\Ercan\blotto.py", line 28, in match
    s = singleMatch()
  File "D:\Ercan\blotto.py", line 5, in singleMatch
    b = random.randint(1, 5050-a)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\random.py", line 215, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\random.py", line 193, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1,1, 0)
```

I couldn't figure out what it means, or what I did wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You are telling your program to create a random number between 1 and 5050 and store it in a. Afterwards you want to get another random number between 1 and 5050-a, now if a is 5050, you would ask it to generate a random number between 1 and 0.

[reference](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html?highlight=randint#random.randint)

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:** the error means that `a` is sometimes equal to `5050`.

**Long answer:** [randint()](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randint) returns a random number lying in the supplied range. If the upper bound is less than the lower bound, then the function fails because there is no actual range to process.

Your first call stores a random number between `1` and `5050` (inclusive) into `a`. Your second call stores a random number between `1` and `5050 - a` (inclusive) into `b`. If the first call returns `5050`, then the second call will fail because the supplied range will be invalid.